# Find the minimum of $p>0$ such that $\frac 1 {1^p}+\frac 1 {2^p}+\frac 1 {3^p}+...$ convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the minimum of $p>0$ such that $\displaystyle \frac 1 {1^p}+\frac 1 {2^p}+\frac 1 {3^p}+...$ convergent.

I know that $\displaystyle \frac 1 {1}+\frac 1 {2}+\frac 1 {3}+...=\infty$ while $\displaystyle \frac 1 {1^2}+\frac 1 {2^2}+\frac 1 {3^2}+...=\frac{\pi^2} 6$. Then what should $p$ be such that the series convergent? Thank you.

Comment: There is no minimum.

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer: Why?

Comment: Because for each such $p$ there is a smaller one where it is still convergent. Following Stahl's hint to find all values of $p$ that work will allow you to make this explicit.

Comment: It converges for $p>1$. As seen by integral test. There is no "lowest $p$" in the set of such values of $p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the integral test for convergence of infinite series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n) < \infty \iff \int_1^{\infty}\!f(x)\,dx <\infty
$$
(provided $f$ is defined and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$)